# Building Ubuntu for ARM TI AM437x

Tags: 14.04, arm, cross-compilation

The following wiki shows how to compile the Ubuntu kernel for arm : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/ARMKernelCrossCompile.
Here, ti-omap4 configuration has been used. I would like to build the kernel for TI AM437x processor. What modifications should be made